# Sending JSON data from Express server to client

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN Stack and really pinned down by this problem. I have an Express server that is calling an external API and getting the data in JSON. I also have a MEAN Stack SPA. What I want to do is that if I go to a certain html page in my SPA, and then click on the button, it will call my Express server and then get the API data from the Express server in json into my html client. I have written the following code but it's not working at all, I am not getting any response in my api_data_list.html page.

My api_data_list.html page:

```html
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  let url = "http://localhost:3000/#!/api_data_list";
  $("button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
        endPoint: url
      };
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function(data) {
            alert("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
              //$('#my_paragraph').text(data);
          }
      });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<h2>List of Guests from GstAPI</h2>

<button>Click here to retrieve data from GstAPI</button>
<p id="my_paragraph"></p>

<table class="table" >
 <tr>
 <th>SNo.</th>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 <th>Room ID</th>
 <th>Actions</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When I run the server (i.e. localhost), this is the index.html page that comes first. I have a link there that takes the user to the api_data_list.html page.

```html
<h2>List of Guests</h2>

<a ui-sref="api_data_list">Click here for GstAPI Guests data</a>
<table class="table" ng-if="guests.length>0">
 <tr>
 <th>SNo.</th>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 <th>Room ID</th>
 <th>Telephone No.</th>
 <th>Actions</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="guest in guests">
 <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
 <td>{{guest.firstname}}</td>
 <td>{{guest.lastname}}</td>
 <td>{{guest.roomid}}</td>
 <td>{{guest.telephoneno}}</td>
 <td>
 <a ui-sref="edit({id:guest._id})">Edit</a> |
 <a href="#" ng-click="deleteGuest(guest._id)">Delete</a>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div ng-if="guests.length==0">
 No guest found !!
</div>
```

My server.js code contains the Node and Express server:

```js
var express = require('express'),
 path = require('path'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 routes = require('./server/routes/web'), //web routes
 apiRoutes = require('./server/routes/api'), //api routes
 connection = require("./server/config/db"); //mongodb connection
var app = express();
getDataFromGstAPI();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

function getDataFromGstAPI(){
 var client_key     = [key];   //Client key
 var client_secret  = [secret];    // Client secret
 var base64EncodedString = Buffer.from(pcc_client_key + ":" + pcc_client_secret).toString('base64');   // Key and Secret are Base64 encoded for Basic authorization
 var request = require("request");    //"request" module is used for making http requests
 var token = '';    //to obtain the access token
 var guests = {};    
 getToken();   //connecting to the GstAPI server to get the token

 function getToken(){
  //making a POST request to server to obtain the access token for oAuth 2.0 (2-legged approach)
  var options = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://connect.gstapi.com/auth/token',
   headers: {
    'authorization': 'Basic ' + base64EncodedString,
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
   }
  };

  app.post('/api_data_list', (req,res) => {
  request(options, function(e,r,body) {
   if(e) throw new Error(e);

   token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

   getGuests(token,res);
  });
  });
    };

 function getGuests(token,res){
  //making a GET request to get the  API using the access token
  var optionsForGETGuests = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://connect.gstapi.com/api/public/guests',
   headers:
   {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
  };


   request(optionsForGETGuests, function (e, r, body) {
    if (e) throw new Error(e);

    //console.log(body);

    guests = JSON.parse(body);

    res.send(guests);

   });

 };
}

var port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
 console.log("Server is running at : http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because of improper configuration of endpoint or routes? Or is it a problem with my jQuery code?

Comment: You'll have to do some homework and narrow down the problem here. Use your console to trace the request end to end - are you getting errors? Is the request from the browser getting a response? Is the server communicating with the API?  Do basic debugging then come back with a more specific question

Comment: I don't see a configured route for that page, you're just calling `getDataFromGstAPI()` inside your server's global scope

Comment: @WillardSolutions Hi, sorry I couldn't explain properly in my question. I did some debugging and also used Postman, and I found that the server communicates with API, and server gets data from API. The only problem that I face here is that the request from the browser (i.e. client jqeury) is not getting any response.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/#!/api_data_list";
```

to:

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/api_data_list";
```

Notice that second example does not have the `#!`

Comment: Hi Jacob! Thanks a lot for your answer. I have changed the url to your preferred form too. However, I am still not getting any response from the Express server.

Comment: I just checked on Postman, but no, I am not getting any response from localhost:3000/pcc_list in Postman.

Comment: I would assume thats cause you are never invoking getDataFromGstAPI() nor getToken() and therefore the endpoint is never registered. Which means express doesn’t know the endpoint exists.